# WOWZA Media server Change protocol from rtmp to http.

Tags: html, mp3, wowza

Our customer has used Wowza server with JWPlayer for mp3 service.
But they want to change protocol from rtmp to http and played in html5 audio tag in IE browser.
Original 
url -> rtmp://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:1935/vod/*definst*/mp3:mu_mp3/00/06/27/0000090005d280ec77d3.mp3

So I change url like ->[http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:1935/vod/*definst*/mp3:mu_mp3/00/06/27/0000090005d280ec77d3.mp3/playlist.m3u8](http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:1935/vod/_definst_/mp3:mu_mp3/00/06/27/0000090005d280ec77d3.mp3/playlist.m3u8)
 But not played both IE and JWPlayer .

1) Is it possible play in IE browser with audio tag?
 2) If it is possible, there's chane need in Wowza server config?

Please, let me know how to change.